# Max barcode size for Apple Wallet and Google Pay passes

Tags: barcode, google-pay, wallet, apple-wallet, aztec-barcode

I would like to allow users of my webapp to add passes to Apple Wallet and Google Pay via their respective add-to-wallet-buttons. The aztec code I intend to use on these passes has many data layers, however, both Apple Wallet and Google Pay passes only display barcodes in a small size.

Does anyone know if there are any problems to be expected with bigger aztec codes? Also, are there any recommendations on maximum aztec data layers for Apple Wallet and Google Pay passes? I've been searching through the documentation but can't seem to find detailed info on recommended barcode specifications.

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens?

Comment: Because that would require partial implementation. If I can find out in advance that my aztec code doesn't meet the requirements or recommendations from Apple and Google it would be wasted work. Also, even if such a test succeeds and my pass can be read once, how reliable are the results? Does it work every time? Hence knowing about requirements and specs from Apple and Google would help a lot.